# async each is running to fast?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have the following code running through an object with async:

```
async.each(Object.keys(shopList), function(key, callback){
    var shop = shopList[key];

    saveOrder(payId, shopList[key], key, req.body, req.user, function(err, newOrder){
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        }else{
            orderCount++;
            console.log("succes!", orderCount, newOrder.number);
            callback();
        }
    })
}, function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR!", err);
    }else{
        console.log("done!");
    }
})
```

In this function a another function is called. This code looks like this:

```
saveOrder = function(payId, shop, nameSlug, body, user, callback){
    console.log("saveOrder");
    var orderNumber = 0;

    Order.findOne().sort({_id:-1}).exec(function(err, latestOrder) {
        if(latestOrder.number){

            orderNumber = latestOrder.number.split("-")[1];
        }

        var order = new Order();
        var date = new Date();

        order.number = date.getFullYear().toString() + date.getMonth().toString() + "-" + (parseInt(orderNumber)+1);

        order.date = date;
        order.payId = payId;
        order.status = {
            status: "Created",
            comment: "",
            date: new Date()
        };
        order.comment = body.comment;

        order.shop = {
            name: shop.name,
            nameSlug: nameSlug
        }

        order.billingDetails = { 
            //order details
        }

        order.sendDetails = {
            //more order details
        }

        order.user = {
           //yep, order details
        }

        var orderItems = [];
        for(p = 0; p < shop.items.length; p++){
            var product = shop.items[p];

            var orderItem = {
                _id: product._id,
                name: product.name,
                brand: product.brand[0].name,
                price: product.price,
                quantity: product.quantity
            }
            orderItems.push(orderItem);
        }
        order.items = orderItems;

        order.save(function(err, result){
            if (err){
                console.log("err!", err);
                return callback(err)
            }else{
                console.log("saved!");
                return callback(null, result);
            }   
        })
    })
}
```

The problem is in the last function. There I try to create a ordernumber which must be unique. I get the last order, split the ordernumber and do a +1.

When I have more objects in my shopList, this function is triggered when he is not ready. With other words, the first order isn't saved then, and I will get the same ordernumber.

How can I fix this? I tried a setTimeout in the async.each but that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue with using `eachSeries()` instead of `each()`

http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mutex using [locks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/locks/).

The callbacks will wait that the mutex is unlocked to lock it making that you won't have simultaneous executions.

```
var locks = require('locks');
var mutex = locks.createMutex();

saveOrder = function(payId, shop, nameSlug, body, user, callback){
    mutex.lock(function () {
        console.log("saveOrder");
        var orderNumber = 0;

        Order.findOne().sort({_id:-1}).exec(function(err, latestOrder) {
            if(latestOrder.number){

                orderNumber = latestOrder.number.split("-")[1];
            }

            var order = new Order();
            var date = new Date();

            order.number = date.getFullYear().toString() + date.getMonth().toString() + "-" + (parseInt(orderNumber)+1);

            order.date = date;
            order.payId = payId;
            order.status = {
                status: "Created",
                comment: "",
                date: new Date()
            };
            order.comment = body.comment;

            order.shop = {
                name: shop.name,
                nameSlug: nameSlug
            }

            order.billingDetails = { 
                //order details
            }

            order.sendDetails = {
                //more order details
            }

            order.user = {
               //yep, order details
            }

            var orderItems = [];
            for(p = 0; p < shop.items.length; p++){
                var product = shop.items[p];

                var orderItem = {
                    _id: product._id,
                    name: product.name,
                    brand: product.brand[0].name,
                    price: product.price,
                    quantity: product.quantity
                }
                orderItems.push(orderItem);
            }
            order.items = orderItems;

            order.save(function(err, result){
                if (err){
                    console.log("err!", err);
                    return callback(err)
                }else{
                    console.log("saved!");
                    return callback(null, result);
                }   
            })
        })
        mutex.unlock(); //don't forget to unlock the mutex
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Hmm, added the code as suggested but still the same effect, the function is triggered and executing his code before he is done...

Comment: why "ordernumber" is not used after being assigned with "latestOrder.number.split("-")[1];"?

Comment: Fixed using the eachSeries instead of each, but I will continue using the mutex.lock function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `async.waterfall` instead of `async.each`, because:

`async.waterfall` - runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their results to the next in the array. http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall

`async.each` - applies the function iteratee to each item in coll, in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With your comment I looked further and I found the function eachSeries, which does the same, with 1 function. So, I'm using that now with the mutex.lock from the other answer!